# Tomcat9 - ERROR 'Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory'

Tags: java, debian, java-11, tomcat9

I'm getting error trying to connect MySQL database via catalina.

Here's an answer I'm getting:
ERROR 'Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)'

There's nothing more in logs. Same app is connecting to Oracle database, and that's working fine.

Here's a part of mysql responsible config:

```
<Resource
        name="jdbc/MyAppMySQL"
        url="jdbc:mysql://{my mysql ip}:3306/{dbname]?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
        username="{user}"
        password="{pass}"

        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxTotal="100"
        maxIdle="30"
        maxWaitMilis="10000"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        validationQuery="select 1 from dual" />
```

If anybody could help me, I'd be very very grateful

#### EDIT

Connection using mysql-client from same machine, using same login data works fine.

Comment: Have you checked the physical connection from your tomcat server to MySQL database by using network tool or mysql client command line?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention that. Connection via mysql-client from same machine, with same data works fine.

Comment: I would suggest: 1, try enable more detailed logs for tomcat. 2, check the MySQL driver you have in Tomcat, whether it is compatible with your MySQL database.

Comment: Installing jdbc connector 5.1 resolved the problem (I've had 8.0)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Resolved - too new jdbc connector was the reason